# How can I allow single underscores only with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How can I allow single underscores only with preg_match?

The regex I made below takes double underscores which is not I want...

```
if(!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\s\_]+$/', $name))
    {
        $error = true;
        echo '<error elementid="name" message="name - please use alpha-numbers and lowercaps only." />';
    }
```

For instance,

```
hello world                  ok
hello_world                  ok
hello__world                 not ok
hello_world__again__         not ok
_hello_world_again_          not ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Including the `_` inside `[]+` allows for multiples. You need to surround it in `[]+` but not include it inside. The entire structure is surrounded by `()+` to allow for multiples of it, but it always ends with letters, numbers, or spaces.

```
/^([a-z0-9\s]+_?[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\s]+)+$/i
```

Breaking it down:

- Outer `()+` allows for multiples of the whole structure
- `[a-z0-9\s]+` Multiple letters, numbers, spaces (not underscore
- `_?[a-z0-9]+` optional *single* underscore inside the multiple letters/numbers/spaces, but not followed by space
- `[a-z0-9\s]+` more letters, numbers, spaces at the end (can't end in underscore)
- `/i` Case insensitive (remove the `i` if you need case sensitivity)

---

```
// Updated to prevent space after underscore
$patt = '/^([a-z0-9\s]+_?[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\s]+)+$/i';

echo preg_match($patt, 'hello world');
// 1
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello_world');
// 1
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello_world_');
// 0
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello__world');
// 0
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello_world how_are you');
// 1
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello_world how_are you_');
// 0
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello_world__ how_are you_');
// 0 
echo preg_match($patt, 'hello_world how_ are you');
// 0
```

Comment: sorry I just found out `hellow_ world` should not be included... is it possible?

Comment: @lauthiamkok How about now? It's gotten a little ugly and could benefit from a lookbehind, but works.

Comment: @lauthiamkok do you also need to prevent space _before_ the `_`?  If so, add another `[a-z0-9]+` just before `_?`

Comment: thanks Michael. it still takes `hello_ world`... maybe I should use more if conditions?

Comment: @lauthiamkok No, sorry the expression at the top of my answer was out of sync with the one in the PHP code, which correctly rejects `hello_ world`. Editfail.